# ng-slideshow cant bind to [product.files] because

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, slideshow

i am trying to build a slideshow with the ng-simple-slideshow (you can find it here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-simple-slideshow).

But i get this error in my console: Uncaught Error:

```
 Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'product.files' since it isn't a known property of 'slideshow'. ("
  </ng-template> -->

  <slideshow [ERROR ->][product.files]="imageUrlArray"></slideshow>
</div>
```

Here is my code:

details.component

```
<div class="pageWrapper space">
  <slideshow [product.files]="imageUrlArray"></slideshow>
</div>
```

details.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';

import { MoltinService } from '../moltin/moltin.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-details',
  templateUrl: './details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./details.component.css']
})
export class DetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  product: any;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private moltinService: MoltinService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params
      .subscribe((params: Params) => {
        this.moltinService.Moltin.Products
          .With(['files'])
          .Get(params.id)
          .then(product => {
            if (product.included.files) {
              product.data.files = product.included.files.map(files => files.link.href);
            }
            this.product = product.data;
            console.log(product);
          });
      });
  }
}
```

my app module.ts but i think i did it right:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { NgxPageScrollModule } from 'ngx-page-scroll';
import {SlideshowModule} from 'ng-simple-slideshow';
```

----------deleted a little bit ----------

```
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
    SlideshowModule,
    NgxPageScrollModule
  ],
  providers: [MoltinService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I am getting the images from moltin a service for e commerce shops.
The json i get looks like this:
[image]

the images in the files array should appear in my slideshow.

Thank you for every help. Thanks Guys ;)

Comment: Slideshow doesn't have an input  of product.files. it does have an input for imageUrls

Comment: so i have to put product.files into imageUrls?

Comment: Be something like `[imageUrls]="yourArrayOfUrls"`